# How to allow for a local event listener method in Corona

Tags: events, lua, coronasdk, listeners

Say I have an eventlistener in a class as follows:

```
Vehicle = {}
...

function Vehicle:touch(event)
  -- do something with self
  return
end

displayObject:addEventListener("touch", self)
```

How do I make the "touch" method local so that nobody gets the urge to call it from outside this class? Without making the compiler complain.

---

Thanks Mike. I didn't realize you could do as UI.lua does:

```
local function newButtonHandler( self, event )
...
end

function newButton( params )
...
button.touch = newButtonHandler
button:addEventListener( "touch", button )
...
end
```

However, the parameters (self, event) in

```
local function newButtonHandler( self, event )
```

is something I haven't seen before - ususally only (event). Does self, as well as event get sent along to the event listener method automagically as an implication of addEventListener?

Anyway, what I originally wanted to do is to have a different object (call it "buttonManager") than the display object be sent along to the class eventListener method, because I need access to buttonManager there. So I thought I could write:

```
button:addEventListener( "touch", buttonManager )
```

But that results in the eventListener not being called at all. How do I get buttonManager to the eventListener?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you could create a separate module for the class you're designing, and make the touch handler a local function to that module. See Corona's `ui.lua` file (included in many of their sample projects) to see how they do it.

```
module(..., package.seeall)

local function newButtonHandler( self, event )
    . . .
end

function newButton( params )

    . . .

    button.touch = newButtonHandler
    button:addEventListener( "touch", button )

    . . .

    return button
end
```

This is boiled down from their code. As you can see, newButtonHandler is local, so it cannot be called by the outside world.

Hope that helps!